# Showing whitespace from text (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Users have been adding breaks for their paragraphs which can be seen in the database when looking at their text columns, like this:

[image]

However, when I display the text on their profile pages, like this:

```
<h5>{{ $user->description }}</h5>
```

The text simply displays as one large paragraph. I am looking to have the line breaks in the database show on the page to split up the paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a CSS issue rather than a Laravel specific issue. You should try set that element to honor white-space:

```
h5 {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

`white-space: pre` is also an option.

You can see here for the variances between the white-space options: 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Answer (score 0):

In your database the field probably has "\n" as newline so to see it in HTML, you need to change `"\n"` to `<br>`, try this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php